# Laravel - Unable to override the create method for a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When overriding the base Laravel model create method, the application fails. No errors are sent back to the browser, and the server logs are empty. The strange thing, it works just fine without the override. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Simplified controller function:

```
public function save(Request $request, $id = 0) {
    $myModel = MyModel::find($id);
    $data = $request->all();

    if (!$myModel) // Create a new row
    {
        $myModel = MyModel::create($data);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This works fine until I add this function to the model:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    // ...

    public static function create($attributes = [])
    {
        return parent::create($attributes);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a different way to implement this. I just need to know why the parent call is failing for me.

Here's some server info...

- Server OS: Windows 7 (personal PC with XAMPP)
- Laravel version 5.4.15
- PHP version 5.6.30

Comment: Instead of naming the function `save()` would it help to name it as `store()` so that it overrides the store method and can be used as a resource route?

Comment: @developernator That didn't make a difference.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. This has only started happening in Laravel 5.4. In L5.3 there wasn't an issue. @dparoli's solution worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explanation is that the public static function create() is not defined in the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.

Is handled as *dynamic* method call, that is is handled by calling the function:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
```

In the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.

At the end the `create()` function is defined in the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.
That is the reason you cant override it in your Model and call parent::create()

IMHO I have not tested entirely, you could try with:

```
public static function create($attributes)
{
    return (new static)->newQuery()->create($attributes);
}
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your answer?

Comment: Which part is not understandable? I explained that parent::create() in Eloquent/Model derived classes does not exist.

Comment: How is one supposed to know that? I just spent the better part of an hour trying to look up the "supposed" **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create()** function and couldn't find it in the API documentation. No mentions of it being a dynamic method call, and besides how am i supposed to know that, when judging by all _looks_, it's a method of the **Model** class. I am thankful for your explanation tho, just wish the documentation was clear enough that i didn't have to ask a stranger on stack overflow about something that should be obvious IMHO.

Comment: @PKSWE overriding the create() function of an eloquent Model is an advanced topic, so you have to dig in the source code. IMHO if the documentation should also cover advanced topics it would be larger than the source code. In the official docs there is an hint regarding what you get calling a static method on an Eloquent Model (i.e. a QueryBuilder instance) here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

Comment: Just so you know, "return (new static)->newQuery()->create($attributes);" works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [events](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#events) instead.

For example as closure:

```
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::created(function (MyModel $myModel) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: This is good to perform supplementary actions *after* the model's been created, but doesn't address the original question of how to override the method and prevent standard model creation from happening.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Based on PiTheNumber's answer and miken32's comment as well as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64935310/288568 the best way seems to be to use the `creating` event and return false,

```
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::creating(function (MyModel $myModel) {
        if($dontWantToCreateIt) {
           return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Together with the `created` even you should have all the same possibilities of customization as if it would be easier possible to overwrite the method.

Answer (score -2):

About errors, you should make sure you have enabled log_errors on your server. About the error, when you extend class and want to override method, it should have same signature, so it should be:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    // Your custom code goes here

    return parent::create($attributes);
}
```

(notice `array` type hinting). Obviously I assume you are going to add something more in this function :)

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem, but I do agree with what you're suggesting. Also, because I'm in a dev environment, the server does output errors. For some reason, this problem is an exception to exceptions. Can't explain why.

Comment: @Siphon So I'm pretty sure the problem is in other place you suggest or you don't show some other important parts of your application

Comment: I have confirmed that my application breaks at exactly that point. I added `die();` calls to before and after that controller line to make sure that was the problem. There may be another important part, but I cannot tell you what that would be.