# How to avoid create record in laravel model creating event

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently using Laravel 8 and I want check a field when my model 'creating' event fired. If my field isn't null, I want cancel creating record.
my event is like below:

```html
protected static function booted(){
    static::creating(function ($contactMessage){
        if(request('birthday') != null)
            //Here I want Stop creating record but don't know how!!!
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return `false` if you want to stop the creation of the record. `Model@performInsert` will check to see if a `false` was returned from any event listener for the `creating` event.